# How to open a notebook focused on a specific tagged cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, filtering, cells, customization

I am preparing lecture notes in *Mathematica* for students, which consist of several tens of notebooks. From time to time I face a necessity in one notebook  to give a reference to some formula of another notebook. The formula in such a case is given in a `DisplayFormulaNumbered` cell, and this cell is tagged.

Now comes my question.

How can I programmatically open the notebook with the formula, such that this cell will be on the screen, possibly, selected, and ready to be seen by the reader?

I will then package this code into a button to put it at the reference, ready to open and look.  The best solution would be, if the all `CellGroups` existing in the document would be collapsed, except for the one containing the tagged cell in question.

To be specific, and to enable one to try, here is a code creating a notebook with three groups of `Section/TextCell/TextCell/DisplayFormulaNumberedCell`. The cells with the formula are tagged by `"L1", "L2"` and `"L3"` correspondingly:

```
 nb = CreateDocument[{CellGroup[{TextCell["The head1", "Section"], 
     TextCell["First text cell"], TextCell["Second text cell"], 
     TextCell["x+y", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", CellTags -> {"L1"}]}], 
   CellGroup[{TextCell["The head2", "Section"], 
     TextCell["First text cell"], TextCell["Second text cell"], 
     TextCell["a+b", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", CellTags -> {"L2"}]}],
   CellGroup[{TextCell["The head3", "Section"], 
     TextCell["First text cell"], TextCell["Second text cell"], 
     TextCell["u/v", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", CellTags -> {"L3"}]}]
   }]
```

Let us try, say, to open it programmatically from another notebook with the `"L2"` cell selected, while the `CellGroups` which do not contain `"L2"` - collapsed.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you. That works perfectly. I only put a command `nb = NotebookOpen["filePath"];` in front of your code to complete it. Why do not you formulate it as a regular answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This procedure seems to do what you are after:

```
Module[{ nb = NotebookOpen["filePath"] },
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]; 
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken[nb, "SelectionCloseAllGroups"];    
  NotebookFind[nb, "L3", All, CellTags]
]
```

Depending of your needs `NotebookLocate` can be used too. It automatically aims at `CellTags` and can open closed notebooks.